# Как добавить на ссылку data-bs-toggle="dropdown" через JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить на ссылку data-bs-toggle="dropdown" через jQuery??

```
<ul>
<li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">
    <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Пункт меню</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Где в вашем пимере `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`? Или вы хотите просто добавить этот атрибут всем `<a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя метод `attr` в jQuery можно сделать так:

```
$(".menu-item a").attr("data-bs-toggle", "dropdown");
```

Если в `attr` указать два аргумента (название атрибута и какое-то значение), то тогда всем элементам с таким селектором `.menu-item a` (он указан в коде), будет назначен атрибут `data-bs-toggle` (тоже был указан в коде), со значением которые вы указываете во втором аргументе.

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ комментариями

Comment: Так можно добавить атрибут data-bs-toggle и его значение dropdown к всем ссылкам из Вашего кода.

Comment: @SwaD не совсем уверен, что это требуется, весь код вполне понятен.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Ну когда есть некая детализация, мол выберем все элементы с ... затем добавим атрибут так то... смотрится гораздо красивее ) Ну как по мне

Comment: @SwaD да пожалуй вы правы, также сочту уместным упомянуть тех, кто не имеет знаний английского, им объяснение будет полезно как никому другому.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Да черт с ним, с английским, тут бы джекверивский расшифровать :)

Comment: @SwaD это точно :)

Answer (score 0):

Замените атрибут href с помощью метода attr. Вместо кавычек, для значения аттрибута используйте

```
&quot;
```

В вашем случае:

```
$("a").attr("href","data-bs-toggle=&quot;dropdown&quot;");
```